# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't retract indents on HTML auto formatting (Ctrl+K+D)

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, indentation, autoformatting

Visual Studio 2010 re-indents HTML text on re-formatting (Ctrl+K+D). It means, when text was already indented after newline, VS tries to re-indent it to fit into optimal block.

```
<p>Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1
     Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2
        Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3</p>
```

becomes

```
<p>Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1
   Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2
   Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3</p>
```

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't retract indents on HTML auto formatting. It means that the original text above becomes:

```
<p>Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1 Line1
     Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2 Line2
     Line2
        Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3 Line3
     Line3</p>
```

How to get the behaviour of VS 2010 in VS 2012 ?

I haven't found a corresponding setting.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have vs 2012 to ensure whether it is right solution.

It might be related to `"Wrap tags that exceed specified length"` (or some other "word wrap") option in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML.

Here is information that such option is present for XAML formatting in that version of vs - [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb763100(v=vs.110))

Here is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877266/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-2008-from-wrapping-lines-when-formatting-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about similar issue in vs 2008

Comment: Thank you for the answer. VS2012 can wrap tags that exceed specific length, and does it well. What it can't do is retract indents and re-arrange lines that could be complemented to reach maximum width.